# How many instructions per cycle do AMD K8 CPUs have?

Tags: cpu, amd-processor

How many instructions per cycle do AMD K8 (preferably AMD Turion x2 64, if it matters) CPUs have? I looked everywhere and I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 according to [this article](http://www.anandtech.com/cpuchipsets/showdoc.aspx?i=2748&p=3).

Answer (score 3):

It's quite a complicated question, how many RISC instructions (after translation of the original CISC instructions of the x86 legacy) a processor can execute in parallel depends on the instruction itself, whether there are pipeline dependencies and free ALU units.

Chances are you can find a list of [how many cycles each specific instruction needs on the AMD website](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/25112.PDF), then the dependency rules, Intel used to publish those specifications and that should normally be public. Interpreting it with modern CPU's is another matter.